# Display post id - product - category and tag in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to display the ID of all posts - products - categories and tags in a separate column in the admin panel of my WordPress theme.

For this purpose, I prepared the following code and placed it in the `functions.php` file:

```
add_filter( 'manage_posts_columns', 'revealid_add_id_column', 5 );
add_action( 'manage_posts_custom_column', 'revealid_id_column_content', 5, 2 );

function revealid_add_id_column( $columns ) {
   $columns['revealid_id'] = '(ID)';
   return $columns;
}

function revealid_id_column_content( $column, $id ) {
  if( 'revealid_id' == $column ) {
    echo $id;
  }
}

$custom_post_types = get_post_types( 
  array( 
     'public'   => true, 
     '_builtin' => true 
  ), 
  'names'
); 

foreach ( $custom_post_types as $post_type ) {
 add_action( 'manage_edit-'. $post_type . '_columns', 'revealid_add_id_column' );
 add_filter( 'manage_'. $post_type . '_custom_column', 'revealid_id_column_content' );
}

$taxonomies = get_taxonomies();

foreach ( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) {
    add_action( 'manage_edit-' . $taxonomy . '_columns', 'revealid_add_id_column' );
    add_filter( 'manage_' . $taxonomy . '_custom_column', 'revealid_id_column_content' );
}
```

This code displays the ID of all posts and products in the last column, but does not show the ID of any category or tag.

I also added the following code to move the ID to the first column (after the checkbox), but by adding this code, a fatal error occurs:

```
function revealid_add_id_column( $columns ) {
    $checkbox = array_slice( $columns , 0, 1 );
    $columns = array_slice( $columns , 1 );

    $id['revealid_id'] = '(ID)';
    
    $columns = array_merge( $checkbox, $id, $columns );
    return $columns;
}
```

**In summary:**
In addition to displaying the ID of posts and products, I want to display the ID of categories and tags as well.

Also, the ID column placed at the end should be moved to the first column (after the check box).

**Thank you very much in advance.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question, you're close, but there's a difference between the hooks for post types and taxonomies: for taxonomies, the hook for the column's content is a filter, not an action (don't ask me why).

For the second question, without seeing what the actual error is, I suspect it's because `$id` is not defined as an array before attempting to set the offset.

Here's my approach (tested):

```php
add_action( 'init', static function () {

    $post_types = get_post_types();
    $taxonomies = get_taxonomies();

    add_filter( 'manage_posts_columns', static function ( $columns ) {
        $first_column  = array_slice( $columns, 0, 1 );
        $second_column = array( 'revealid_id' => 'ID' );
        $columns       = array_slice( $columns, 1 );

        return $first_column + $second_column + $columns;
    } );

    add_action( 'manage_posts_custom_column', static function ( $column, $id ) {
        if ( 'revealid_id' !== $column ) {
            return;
        }

        echo $id;
    }, 10, 2 );

    foreach ( $post_types as $post_type ) {

        add_filter( 'manage_edit-' . $post_type . '_columns', static function ( $columns ) {
            $first_column  = array_slice( $columns, 0, 1 );
            $second_column = array( 'revealid_id' => 'ID' );
            $columns       = array_slice( $columns, 1 );

            return $first_column + $second_column + $columns;
        } );

        add_action( 'manage_' . $post_type . '_custom_column', static function ( $column, $id ) {
            if ( 'revealid_id' !== $column ) {
                return;
            }

            echo $id;
        }, 10, 2 );

    }

    foreach ( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) {

        add_filter( 'manage_edit-' . $taxonomy . '_columns', static function ( $columns ) {
            $first_column  = array_slice( $columns, 0, 1 );
            $second_column = array( 'revealid_id' => 'ID' );
            $columns       = array_slice( $columns, 1 );

            return $first_column + $second_column + $columns;
        } );

        add_filter( 'manage_' . $taxonomy . '_custom_column', static function ( $content, $column, $id ) {
            if ( 'revealid_id' !== $column ) {
                return $content;
            }

            return $id;
        }, 10, 3 );

    }

} );
```

You will absolutely want to reduce the repetition; I did so here to be very clear on the differences.

Comment: Thank you. It was as I wanted.